# jQuery.Event -- where's my data?

Tags: jquery, events

I've got some code that looks like this (shortened):

```
$.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: formData,
    type: $form.find('input[name=_method]').val() || $form.attr('method') || 'POST'
}).done(function (data, textStatus, $xhr) {
    var eventParams = {
        xhr: $xhr,
        validator: validator
    };
    $form.trigger($.Event('ajaxify-success',eventParams));
});
```

I use it like this:

```
$('#label-form').on('ajaxify-success', function(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
});
```

But `ev.data` is always `undefined`. If I modify `eventParams` to sutff the data back in:

```
var eventParams = {
    xhr: $xhr,
    validator: validator,
    data: data
};
```

It *still* doesn't work. jQuery is doing something to actively remove the data. Why? I basically want to propagate the ajax done event and add in a couple extra properties of my own. How can I do that without losing `data`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `data` as some arbitrary event parameter as it's reserved by jQuery for [Event.data](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/).

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dcvj4dv/2/)

Comment: Oh..it's used as some kind of context var so that you can link the callback  back to the point of binding. I guess I can see why they're overriding it then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Then per the previous answer, you can't use 'data'... change the variable name and you're good to go. See this snippet:

```js
var eventParams = {
    xhr: 'myXHR',
    validator: 'myValidator',
    mydata: 'myData'
};

$('#label-form').on('ajaxify-success', function(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
});

$('#label-form').trigger(jQuery.Event( 'ajaxify-success', eventParams ));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="label-form">form</form>
```

Comment: Yes, if you want to actually pass things via `event.data` then you assign them when you attach the handler like `$('something').on('ajaxify-success', data, function (e) {});`.

Comment: You've changed the .trigger line. I wanted to put my custom properties inside the event object.